# Does the height of the water column affect how fast water pours through a water filter?

Tags: fluid-statics

I have a water filter where I fill the top with water and it slowly pours through the filter. To fill the bottle, I have to refill the top at least once. Now I am wondering if it pours at different speeds depending on whether I refill it completely after it runs empty or fill it once and then let the water tap slowly refill it as it pours into the bottle.

The force (gravity) pushing the water through the filter is the same, so it should be the same speed, but on the other hand, the water pressure at the bottom of the water column increases with the height of the water column, so the water should flow faster through the filter. What is the solution to this paradox?

Comment: yes, it will be faster, in the "same" way that if you drop a ball from a larger height its velocity will be larger when it reaches the bottom. Of course, this is a fluid, the water does not instantaneously  move from the top to the bottom, but if you think about the problem in terms of mechanical energies, the idea is similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key variable here is water pressure, not gravity.  Gravity is the force driving the increase in water pressure as the mass increases in this case, but it's the water pressure that determines how fast water will pass through a filter.  People get messed up by the whole "objects fall at the same rate in a vacuum" thing, but these are different problems.  A heavier object dropped from the same height might fall at the same rate, but it will make a bigger boom when it hits the ground.  Their acceleration might be the same, but the larger object has more force because F=MA, not just A.  When it comes to *forcing* a substance through something restrictive, that mass makes a difference.  If you stick a 1 oz block of playdoh on some metal grating, it will just sit there, but a 1 ton block of playdoh would start pushing through the grating.  By the same token, 1 ton of water will put more pressure on a filter than 1 oz of water.  At very low pressures, depending on the pore size of the filter, the water might even just sit there like the playdoh.